# Xcodebuild failing to pick up environment values from project file?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6, MacOSX.

I have a globally visible environment setting:

```
ICU_SRC=~/Documents/icu/source
```

This *really is* an environment setting, it's set at login time. When I open up Terminal, it's there.

In my project, under `Header Search Paths` I've added this:

```
$(ICU_SRC)/i18n
$(ICU_SRC)/common
```

These expand correctly when I compile inside the IDE. When I look at the build results, I see this:

```
-I/Users/eric.grunin/Documents/icu/source/i18n
-I/Users/eric.grunin/Documents/icu/source/common
```

When I build from the command line, however, it fails. What I see is this:

```
-I/i18n
-I/common
```

Here's the command I'm using to compile:

> /usr/bin/env -i xcodebuild -project my_project.xcodeproj -target
>   "my_program" -configuration Release -sdk macosx10.6 build

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited to add:**

Apple  explains [Setting environment variables for user processes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it works better if you specify the env vars **before** the `xcodebuild` command, as in

```
# NOT this
xcodebuild ... options ... SOMEVAR=somevalue

# But this instead works better
SOMEVAR=somevalue xcodebuild ... options ...
```

This works especially well for `PRODUCT_NAME` when working with cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "connect" xcode build to Xcode using your scheme.

From xcodebuild side :
xcodebuild ... options ... **yourVAR**=yourValue

From Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Arguments -> Environment Variables
(name) someKey (Value) $**yourVAR**

The key is that the name of **yourVAR** in xcodebuild will be referred from Xcode arguments, by using '$'.

In order to access the environment variable later from code, you need to use

> ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["someKey"]

[image: Xcode Environment Variables from your Scheme]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 years old but it is still relevant.   I just spent a day tracking down the fact that xcodebuild looks at the CC environmental variable (if it is set) and will probably do the wrong thing.  I am using xcodebuild version 6.1.1  (build version 6A2008a).

The error I get if CC is set is:

PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:1690

Details:  commandPath should be a string, bit it is nil

Hints: none

I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: No idea if this is right (I'm no longer on that project), but thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experiments, xcodebuild does not really pick up environment variable from Shell. To make xcode honor environment variables, we have to pass them explicitly:

```
  export ICU_SRC_ENV=~/Documents/icu/source 
  /usr/bin/env -i xcodebuild -project my_project.xcodeproj \
                             -target "my_program" \
                             -configuration Release \
                             -sdk macosx10.6 \
                             build \
                             ICU_SRC=$ICU_SRC_ENV
```

The command above passes system environment variable to xcodebuild environment variable. You may reference it in your xcodeproj by $(ICU_SRC) notation. BTW, I used different names so we can distinguish two variables, but you can also use the same variable name.

The ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist is indeed equivalant with the export line in my example. It's for Shell only.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems that xcodebuild *does* pick up at least CC from its environment (the shell from which you run it, for instance), though... (Which in my case is *not* what I want;) Sigh, why can't this stuff be documented clearly.

Answer (score -1):

The "environment" settings set using Xcode are not *really* environment variables; they're only known to Xcode. If you want them to be really environment variables, visible from the command line, you have to use the following shell command:

```
user@host ~ $ export ICU_SRC="~/Documents/icu/source"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it really is an environment setting, I set it in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`, and it's visible in Terminal. But xcodebuild seems to be thinking it's something else.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know about this.